# How to get a result set of string using like or compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008

```
Table 1 varchar(100)

Values1 (Always one row)

123ABC456

Table2 varchar(200)

Values2 (Mulitple Rows)

123ABC456
123ABC456INV1
123ABC456_JULY
JULY123ABC456
0123ABC456
99123ABC456
JULY 123ABC456 INV 1
123JULYABC456
123_ABC456
```

I want to select exact value1 match from value2 and First 9 characters values2 should be matched from value1. Below for your reference

```
123ABC456 - Exact Match
123ABC456INV1 - First 9 Character Matched
123ABC456_JULY - First 9 Character Matched
JULY123ABC456 - No Match
0123ABC456 - No Match
99123ABC456 - No Match
JULY 123ABC456 INV 1 - No Match
123JULYABC456 - No Match
123_ABC456 - No Match
```

Query like

Select * from table2 where values like '% table1 values %'

Expected Output

```
123ABC456
123ABC456INV1
123ABC456_JULY
```

Kindly advise and support for the query

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT t2.Values2 
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON (t2.Values2 LIKE t1.Values1 + '%')
```

It does not care for  Values1's length which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.Values2
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 
   ON LEFT(t2.Values2,9) = t1.Values1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```
select DISTINCT Table2.Value
from   Table1
join   Table2
    on Table1.value = left(Table2.value,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)** function.

> Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of
>   characters.

```
SELECT Table2.Values2 
FROM Table2
JOIN Table1 
ON LEFT(Table2.Values2, 9) = Table1.Values1
```

Comment: How do you know that the Values1 lenght is exactly 9?

Comment: As OP said: `I want to select exact value1 match from value2 and First 9 characters values2 should be matched from value1.`

Comment: OK my bad, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SUBSTR](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187748%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON SUBSTR(t1.values,1,9) = SUBSTR(t2.values,1,9)
```

Edit: SUBSTR is more database engine agnostic - so, more portable than LEFT.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the match string first and as you want the same prefix so you should use ='value%'

```
DECLARE @match NVARCHAR(255)
SELECT @match= (select * from @Table1) + '%';
Select * from @Table2 where value like @match
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also valid:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Value2 LIKE (SELECT Value1 FROM Table1) + '%'
```